# MariaDB - how to drop partition on master but not on slave

Tags: mariadb

My use case is that I want to have a master with main data organized into partitions - one partition per day (each day a new partition is created). The master should only keep most recent 10 days of data and I need the slaves to keep all.

How do I `ALTER TABLE ... DROP PARTITION` on master without being replicated on slaves?

I seems to me that somehow I have to instruct the master not to write this operation into bin-log, but how do I do it?

Comment: I don't think you can do this in replication. MariaDB doc is not clear about it, but [MySQL doc is](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-features-partitioning.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altering a table to make it different between Master and Slave is asking for trouble.  Subsequent operations may fail due to the differences.  Caveat emptor.

```
SET sql_log_bin = OFF;
ALTER ...;             -- or any other statement
SET sql_log_bin = ON;
```

That runs the query on the Master, but does not put it into the replication stream, thereby preventing it from being executed on the Slave(s).

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-sql-log-bin.html

I feel sure that MariaDB works the same as MySQL.

If you are using some "cluster", such as Galera, then read about TOI and RSU.  http://galeracluster.com/documentation-webpages/schemaupgrades.html